# Timestamp to list of month and year using Python

Tags: python, pandas, graph, timestamp, bokeh

I want to get from a list of Timestamps to a list of the month and year.

the output for date_list is

```
Out[16]: 
[Timestamp('2014-09-30 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2014-10-31 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2014-11-30 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2014-12-31 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2015-01-31 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2015-02-28 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2015-03-31 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2015-04-30 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2015-05-31 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2015-06-30 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2015-07-31 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2015-08-31 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2015-09-30 00:00:00')]
```

I want it to be [Sep 2014, Oct 2014,...Sep 2015]

If I try to graph it as is, I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'str'` which makes sense. I don't know how to get from Timestamp to the value that the plot will accept. I tried using datetime.datetime(date_list) and got `TypeError: an integer is required`

I also tried `pd.to_datetime(formatted.index, format='%b %Y').tolist()` but this gives the same timestamp output.

EDIT: More information on the code.

My original dataframe looks like this:

```
groupname                             A                B     Total
recvd_dttm                                                      
2014-09-30                            21               55     76
2014-10-31                            20               66     86
2014-11-30                            18               45     63
2014-12-31                            11               46     57
2015-01-31                            25                2     27
2015-02-28                             8                1      9
2015-03-31                            29                1     30
2015-04-30                             8               66     74
2015-05-31                            10               78     88
2015-06-30                            21               59     80
2015-07-31                            14               86    100
2015-08-31                             8               90     98
2015-09-30                             2                2      4
```

Where I retrieved recv_dttm using an earlier dataframe `df['recvd_dttm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['recvd_dttm'])`

Then I made

```
total_list = formatted['Total'].values.tolist()
date_list = formatted.index.tolist()
```

Comment: please show what `date_list` is. You are showing `formatted.index.tolist()`. Where is `Timestamp` defined?

Comment: @Pynchia whoops I had a typo. formatted.index.tolist() = date_list. The output shown is date_list.

Comment: ok, thank you. Still your answer to my question is partial. What is `Timestamp`?

Comment: @Pynchia I am not quite sure how to answer that question. I put in more information of the code to see if that would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the timestamp's own `strftime` to format:

```
[date.strftime("%b %Y") for date in date_list]
```

Comment: Yes! Perfect, Thank you very much.

Comment: so it is simply a date uh? Pardon my ignorance, but where is the `Timestamp` class printout coming from? If I use `datetime.date.fromtimestamp(time.time())` I get `datetime.date(2015, 9, 2)`. Please help me understand how that date was created.

Comment: @Pynchia It's a pandas Timestamp object (I guessed it, you're right that it's not obvious).

Comment: Alright, thank you. I've never seen a panda, yet. Maybe a `pandas` tag would have helped a lot.

Comment: @Pynchia: `isinstance(Timestamp, datetime) == True` i.e., you can use any datetime method with a `Timestamp` object.